# Behavior of Scala for/comprehension implicit transformation of numerical types?

Tags: scala, types, numerical-methods, numerical, autoboxing

I'm trying to understand the behavior of Scala for-loop implicit box/unboxing of "numerical" types.  Why does the two first fail but not the rest?

1) Fails:

`scala> for (i:Long <- 0 to 10000000L) {}`

```
      <console>:19: error: type mismatch;<br>
      found   : Long(10000000L)
      required: Int
              for (i:Long <- 0 to 10000000L) {}
                                  ^
```

2> Fails:

`scala> for (i <- 0 to 10000000L) {}`

```
      <console>:19: error: type mismatch;
      found   : Long(10000000L)
      required: Int
          for (i <- 0 to 10000000L) {}
                         ^
```

3) Works:

`scala> for (i:Long <- 0L to 10000000L) {}`

4) Works:

`scala> for (i <- 0L to 10000000L) {}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the for-loop:

```
0 to 1L   //error
0 to 1    //fine
0L to 1L  //fine
0L to 1   //fine
```

It's just because the `to` method available to `Int` expects an `Int` as its argument.  So when you give it a `Long` it doesn't like it, and you get an error.

Here's the definition of the `to` method, found on `RichInt`:

```
def to(end: Int): Range.Inclusive = Range.inclusive(self, end)
```

Comment: Is there an option in the REPL or compiler you can use to generate "de-shugard" output from the "for/comprehension" ?

Comment: Yep, you can use `scalac -print`.

Comment: Thanks, any similar option/switch for the REPL?

Comment: The "-print" flag gives you the full "scala -> java" translation. Is it possible to printout only for/comrehension desugard part on the scala level?

Comment: `scalac -print` does not print a scala -> java translation, because scala code does not get translated to java. `scalac -print` prints the scala code, that is finally translated to bytecode. It is not possible to desugar just the for-comprehensions. But basically all for-comprehensions get translated to nested flatMaps where the innermost is a simple map.

Comment: @dhg: Although your observation is quite correct I think implicit conversion of "for/comprehension" expressions is inconsistent and needs to be improved. Please see my argument below and feel free to comment what you think!

Answer (score -3):

The desugaring and implicit transformation of numerical types is inconsistent i.e differ between the "for/comprehension" expressions compared to assignment operations. Please feel free to prove otherwise or at least point where the argument below is flawed:

In fact, during numeric assignment the **Destination type** is dominant.

`var l:Long = 0` becomes:
  `val l: Long = 0L`

`var l:Long  = 0.toInt` becomes:
`var l: Long = 0.toInt.toLong`

During "for/comprehension" expressions the **Source type** is dominant:

`for (i:Long <- 0 to 1000000000L) { }` becomes:
 `0.to(1000000000L).foreach(((i: Long) => ()))`

`for (i <- 0L to 1000000000L) { }`  becomes:
`scala.this.Predef.longWrapper(0L).to(1000000000L).foreach[Unit](((i: Long) => ()))`

(ps: output generated with the "-Xprint:typer -e" compiler flag. ds)

Comment: The term is "_target typing_" [Martin O's book "Program in Scala" section 8.4]. There are several other references like "closures are constructed automatically depending on the expected type (target typing)." but that doesn't apply (obviously) to for-comprehensions i.e the mental and the logical models are inconsistent: Also see: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905659"

Comment: Please don't down-vote without leaving a comment why. Thank you!