# Why is implicit transformation of numerical types inconsistent between "for/comprehension" expressions compared to(!) assignment operations?

Tags: scala, types, list-comprehension, implicit-conversion, numerical

Why is desugaring and implicit transformation of numerical types inconsistent between "for/comprehension" expressions compared to(!) assignment operations?

I'm sure there are many general perspectives on this but I couldn't figure out a concise and logical explanation for the current behavior. [Ref:["Behavior of Scala for/comprehension..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888804/behavior-of-scala-for-comprehension-implicit-transformation-of-numerical-types) 
]
For the sake of correctness all translations below was generated with the scala compiler ("scalac -Xprint:typer -e")

For example, during implicit numeric assignment transformation the **Destination type** is dominant:

Source: `var l:Long = 0`
Result : `val l: Long = 0L`

Source: `var l:Long  = 0.toInt`
Result : `var l: Long = 0.toInt.toLong`

During implicit transformation of "for/comprehension" expressions the **Source type** is dominant:

Source: `for (i:Long <- 0 to 1000000000L) { }`
Result : `0.to(1000000000L).foreach(((i: Long) => ()))`

Source: `for (i <- 0L to 1000000000L) { }`
Result : `scala.this.Predef.longWrapper(0L).to(1000000000L).foreach[Unit](((i: Long) => ()))`

Comment: Can someone please explain why anyone would down-vote a _Question_ (especially without leaving an explanation)? Is this the infamous Scala community attitude i've heard about .i.e "don't ask a question if don't know what you are talking about…"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two completely different things going on. First, assignment:

```
val l: Long = 0
```

We have an `Int` that is being assigned to a `Long`. That shouldn't be possible, unless there is an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Long`, which we can verify like this:

```
scala> implicitly[Int => Long]
res1: Int => Long = <function1>
```

Since there is such a conversion, that conversion is applied.

Next, the for-comprehension:

```
for (i:Long <- 0 to 1000000000L) { }
```

This doesn't work because the `to` method called on `Int` (actually called on `scala.runtime.RichInt`, through an implicit conversion) only admits an `Int` argument, not a `Long` argument.

The `to` method called on a `Long` (`RichLong`) does admit a `Long` argument, but there are two reasons why that doesn't apply on the expression above:

1. To get to `RichLong`'s `to` method, the `Int` would have to be first converted into a `Long`, and then into a `RichLong`, and Scala does not apply two chained implicit conversions, ever. It can only convert `Int` to `RichInt` or to `Long`, not `Int` to `Long` to `RichLong`.
2. To apply such conversion, there would have to be some indication a `Long` was required in first place, and there isn't. The `i: Long` does not refer to the type of `0 to 1000000000L`, whereas `l: Long` does refer to the type of `0` in the first example.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the input! Chained implicit conversions was the key. You don't happen to know where the AST/parser for the "for-comprehensions" is located in the Scala source tree, do you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found the for-comprehension AST/parser in:  "scala/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/TreeBuilder.scala"  at apros line 300:

  /** Create tree for for-comprehension <for (enums) do body> or
  *   <for (enums) yield body> where mapName and flatMapName are chosen
  *  corresponding to whether this is a for-do or a for-yield.
  *  The creation performs the following rewrite rules:
  *
  *    for (P <- G) E   ==>   G.foreach (P => E)
  *

Comment: Btw, the term I was looking for is "_target typing_" (Martin O's book "Program in Scala" section 8.4). I've also seen several other references like "closures are constructed automatically depending on the expected type (target typing)." but that doesn't apply (obviously) to for-comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "destination type" and "source type", but I don't see any problem.

If you have an `Int`, you can assign it to be a `Long`.  That's fine because the range of `Int` is subset of the range of `Long`.  You can't pass a `Long` when you expect an `Int` because `Long` has a larger range and, thus, might generate invalid `Int` values.  And the bit about `to` methods is answered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888804/behavior-of-scala-for-comprehension-implicit-transformation-of-numerical-types).

Going through your cases:

```
var l:Long = 0         // fine because Int up-casts to Long

var l:Long = 0.toInt   // fine because Int up-casts to Long

for (i:Long <- 0 to 1000000000L) { } // bad because...
0 to 1000000000L // bad because RichInt.to doesn't accept a Long argument

for (i <- 0L to 1000000000L) { }     // fine because...
0L to 1000000000L // fine because RichLong.to accepts a Long argument, and produces a Range of Longs
```

The cases in your `for` examples have nothing to do with the `for`.  It only has to do with the fact that you are calling the `to` method.  An explanation:

`0 to 1000000000L` is syntactic sugar for `0.to(1000000000L)` since `to` is just a method. When you call `to` on an `Int`, the implicit conversion to `RichInt` happens, so you're really calling `(new scala.runtime.RichInt(0)).to(1000000000L)`.  But, since `RichInt`'s `to` method only accepts an `Int` argument, passing in a `Long` (ie, `1000000000L`) is illegal since `Long` cannot be cast to `Int` (since it might contain values that are out of `Int`'s range.

`0L to 1000000000L` is syntactic sugar, again, for `0L.to(1000000000L)`.  But now, since the `to` method is being called on a `Long`, the implicit conversion is to `RichLong`: `(new scala.runtime.RichLong(0L)).to(1000000L)`.  And, since `RichLong`'s `to` method accepts a `Long` as a parameter, then everything is fine, because that's what you're giving it.

**EDIT based on your comments:**

It seems like your confusion here is derived from your belief that `=` and `to` should work the same way.  They do not, and should not.  The assignment operator, `=`, is a very special keyword in Scala (and any language) whereas `to` is not a keyword at all -- it's just a method that happens to be found on both `RichInt` and `RichLong`.

That said, there is still no inconsistency.  Here's why:

Scala allows you to automatically cast *up*, but not *down*.  The reason for this is very simple: if an B is is a kind of A, then an B can be substituted for a A without fear.  The opposite is not true.

Lets assume you have two classes:

```
class A
class B extends A

val a: A = null
val b: B = null
```

So think about assignments:

```
val x: A = b  // fine, since B is a subtype of A, so b *is* an A
val x: B = a  // error, since As aren't necessarily Bs
```

Not lets look at function calls:

```
def f(x: A) {}  // only accept As
f(b)            // fine, because a B *is* an A

def g(x: B) {}  // only accept Bs
g(a)            // error, because As aren't necessarily Bs
```

So you can see, for both assignment operators and functions, you can substitute the a subtype for its supertype.  If you think of `Int` as a kind of `Long` (with a more limited range), then it is perfectly analogous.  Now, since *methods* are pretty much just functions sitting on a class, we would expect the behavior to be the same regarding arguments.

So think about what you are asking for when you say that `RichInt.to(Int)` should be able to accept a `Long`.  This would mean that Scala would perform some automatic and safe conversion from `Long` to `Int`, which doesn't make sense.

FINALLY: if your real issue is that you just think that `RichInt` should have a method `to(Long)`, then, well, I guess that's something to complain to the language designers about.  But they'd probably just tell you to use `.toLong` and get on with your life.

Comment: @dbg: I concur (but the range issue is a total different beast ;-) regarding _how_ things currently works. But it doesn't anyware state the logical reason _why_ the implicit transformation model follows different rules for assignment operations and desugared for/comprehensions. To elaborate the destination and source type, it's merely about RHS/LHS-rules and what side that takes precedence when evaluating the types during implicit transformations...

Comment: (Continued)
For example a different but a more natural (IMO) desugar rule for "for (i <- 0 to 1000000000L) { }" would use the RHS-type (dest type) i.e to(T) thus producing "0L.to(…)" rather than "0.to(…)". This would also follow the same mental model as for the assignment of numerical types.

Comment: @dbg Thanks for the update! I think you finally got the principal argument that I aimed at ;-). Now, as you described it so well there is no doubt there exists different logical models for =/to regarding numerical implicit type conversations. 

But I don't think "RichInt" per se, or any other NumT.to(NumT) for that matter, is the issue here. The real issue is the precedence to determine implicit datatype conversion that varies in behavior between the logical models.

Comment: Finally, I'm still quite convinced that if some language designer would harmonize the implicit conversion models it would certainly make life much easier for the application developers. 

Anyhow, thanks for taking your time!